# Is there any way to update value in Redis?

Tags: asp.net-core, caching, redis, stackexchange.redis

I use Redis Desktop Manager in windows 10 for caching in ASP.Net Core 3.1 by `StackExchange.Redis` library.

Except delete and then again add new Key-Value in Redis, is there any way for updating value by key?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just do `set <key> <value>` again and the value will be overwrite.

Answer (score 2):

```
  using (ConnectionMultiplexer redis = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(""))
    {
       IDatabase db = redis.GetDatabase();
       string age = "11";
       db.StringSet("age", age);
    }
```

---

you want to update "age"  25,you can reuse db.StringSet("age", "25");

Answer (score 0):

```
 var content = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(JsonSerializer.Serialize(dto));
 await _cache.SetAsync("Key", content);
```

dto is the value sent by Action